# Including path length in variable length query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query that currently returns all of the relationships from a given node with a variable length path:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name = ({name})
OPTIONAL MATCH path=n-[*..2]-(c)
WHERE n <> c
WITH rels(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH DISTINCT rel
RETURN startnode(rel).name as source, endnode(rel).name as target,  rel.average_alignment
```

I'm looking to add the path length as part of the return:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name = ({name})
OPTIONAL MATCH path=n-[*..2]-(c)
WHERE n <> c
WITH rels(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH DISTINCT rel
RETURN startnode(rel).name as source, endnode(rel).name as target,  rel.average_alignment, length(path)
```

How does one include the path length along with all of the relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WITH` clause drops all previously defined identifiers (like `path`) unless they specified in the clause. Your first `WITH` clause did not specify `path` (or just the length of the path), so it was dropped.

Something like this should work for you:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name = {name}
OPTIONAL MATCH path = (n)-[*..2]-(c)
WHERE n <> c
WITH LENGTH(path) AS lth, RELS(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH DISTINCT lth, rel
RETURN STARTNODE(rel).name as source, ENDNODE(rel).name as target,  rel.average_alignment, lth;
```